# Nested IF statements in Excel, or maybe another formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

thanks in advance for talking a look.

I am building a maintenance spreadsheet and need help creating an IF formula to help keep track of upcoming maintenance on trucks/trailers.

My end goal is this:

If the dispatcher is X, use 18,000 miles for A service and 30,000 for B service. Otherwise, if its any other dispatcher, use 20,000 for A and 40,000 for B.

I have the formulas created for the latter already, they are:

`A: =IF(P4>=(T4+20000), "A", "")`

`B: =IF(P4>=(R4+40000), "B", "")`

This will basically compare the current mileage of the truck (P) to the mileage at the time of the specified service (T for 20k, R for 40k). If the current mileage is above the number, that column will get a mark with either A or B depending on which is needed.

What I need to do is first compare the dispatcher before this formula happens. So lets say if "allan" is in the dispatcher field for that row, use the 18000/30000 mileage increments otherwise use 20000/40000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your two IFs inside an outer third one like this (assuming Dispatcher is in column D, for example):

```
=IF($D4="Alan",IF(P4>(T4+18000),"A",""),IF(P4>(T4+20000),"A",""))
```

being slightly more sly, you could put the dispatcher "switch" in the middle of the other one:

```
=IF(P4>(T4+(IF($D4="Alan",18000,20000)),"A","")
```

or even use the comparison as a simple true/false statement which Excel will treat as 1/0 as soon as you do maths on it:

```
=IF(P4>(T4+20000-2000*($D4="Alan")),"A","")
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. Will be poking around with this today. Thank ya AdamV.